# Uploading image file from website on yahoo server causes 410 gone error message when trying to access it

Tags: php, image, upload, http-status-code-410

I have a form that lets users upload a photo of themselves. This seems to work. The photo does exist on the server once uploaded. When I try to access the file I get a "403 forbidden - you don't have permission to access this url on this sever" and also I get "Additionally, a 410 Gone error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

This is the code I have for uploading the image.

```
$target_path = "images/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadpic']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadpic']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
 {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadpic']['name']). " has been uploaded";
 } 
else
 {
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
 }
```

Comment: Okay so I found out that the image being upload didn't have the right permissions. How do I change the permission in the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [chmod()](http://php.net/chmod) for Unix-like systems.

Be warned that your script will unconditionally overwrite the destination file. Maybe this is what you wanted, but consider what could happen if that $target_path is Web-accessible and a malicious uploads a new 'index.php' or whatever.

Comment: Yeah that's a good warning. So far I'm leaving it the way it was so i can "review" any uploads before making them active.

Answer (score 0):

You must check the configuration of your destination path:

> 403 forbidden -> You don't have
>   permission to enter that directory...

You need to change the chmod of that directory...

```
410 Gone error -> The server couldn't found the proper error document to present with the 403 forbidden message (at htaccess you can set this up)
```

If you don't want this message, you need to create a custom one...

Comment: how do i change the chmod of that directory?